# How multiple channels can be combined to create a larger single channel? (Ex 1024x8x8 to 64x32x32)

Tags: pytorch

I'm a very beginner of pytorch.

I want to make multiple channel data of one pixel into one channel like below, without using for loop:

[image]

Hence, in this case, 1024x8x8 to 64x32x32.

Can you please what function I can use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simply to reshape the tensor [reshape()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html#torch.reshape).
Here's an example:

```
a = torch.linspace(0, 1023, 1024)  # torch.Size([1024])
b = a.reshape(1, 32, 32)           # torch.Size([1, 32, 32])
```

**EDIT:**
To do it column-wise, you need to transpose the tensor. So in this case it is as follows:

```
a = torch.ones((1024, 8, 8))  # torch.Size([1024, 8, 8])
b = a.transpose(0, 2)         # torch.Size([8, 8, 1024])
b = b.reshape((64, 32, 32))   # torch.Size([64, 32, 32])
```

Comment: In the case of a 2d matrix, isn't it reshaped in row order? I want to do it in channel order.

Comment: You are right, the reshape function does row-wise.